# Separating phrases occuring a file-Unix Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a file with tags for some file paths. they appear in sets as shown below:-

```
comp1 : path1
comp2 : path2
comp3 : path3
comp1 : path4
comp1 : path5
comp2 : path6
comp1 : path7
comp2 : path8
comp3 : path9
comp4 : path10
comp1 : path11
comp2 : path12
```

where

- `compN` :- are the tags
- `pathN` :- paths for different files

the expected output is: 

`comp1 : path11

comp2 : path12` 
I want to extract the last set from this file. but the problem is, these sets vary in the number of lines, i.e., some have just one line, some have upto ten. Is my doubt now clear?

Comment: 1. Question not clear.  2. What did you try?

Comment: you want comp1,comp2 set right?

Comment: Can you give us an example of that last set? Do you mean one for comp1, one for comp2, one for comp3 and one for comp4?

Comment: You posted sample input so that's good, but you need to also post your expected output given that input plus a description of why that'd be the expected output. You say you want the last "set" but you don't tell us what constitutes a "set".

Comment: Why would your output be `comp1 : path11; comp2 : path12` instead of `comp4 : path10; comp1 : path11; comp2 : path12`? You seem to want your output to start with the last occurrence of a key value but why is that value `comp1` as opposed to any other value such as `comp4`? You still haven't explained what a "set" is or WHY that would be your expected output.

Comment: for him set must begin with first letter which is comp1. comp1,comp2,comp3 set1 , comp1 set2, comp1,comp2 set3, comp1,comp2,comp3,comp4 set4, comp1,comp2 set5(desired output).

Comment: Hang on, I just noticed that "clarification" came from @user1502952, not from the OP, Shreedhar, so it's just some other posters opinion. Darn, wish I'd spotted that before posting a solution to potentially the wrong problem. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^comp1 /{set=""} {set=set $0 ORS} END{printf "%s",set}' file
comp1 : path11
comp2 : path12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sort for that:

```
$ sort -u file
comp1 
comp2 
comp3 
comp4
```

The `-u` flag tells sort to only keep unique lines

Or if you must use awk, you can do

```
awk '!a[$0]++' file
```

***Answer to updated question***

Use this awk command:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=$0}END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
comp1 : path11
comp2 : path12
comp3 : path9
comp4 : path10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>cat comp.txt
comp1
comp2
comp3
comp4
comp1
comp2
comp3
comp1
comp2
comp1
comp2
comp3
comp4
>sort comp.txt | uniq
comp1
comp2
comp3
comp4
```

Comment: Why pipe to `uniq` though, when you can just use the `-u` flag in the sort, and save a process?

Comment: I don't see any reason for using two processes other than demonstrating, that when you already have your input sorted, it is enough to use the `uniq` command. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne '$count++;push @a,$_;$i=$count if(/comp1/);END{print join "\n",@a[($i-1)..(scalar(@a)-1)]}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
comp1
comp2
comp3
comp4
comp1
comp2
comp3
comp1
comp2
comp1
comp2
comp3
comp4
> perl -lne '$count++;push @a,$_;$i=$count if(/comp1/);END{print join "\n",@a[($i-1)..(scalar(@a)-1)]}' temp
comp1
comp2
comp3
comp4
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Python solution is more readable then the Perl

```
for line in sorted(set(open('comp.txt').readlines())):
  print line.strip()
```

you would run it like

```
echo -e "for line in sorted(set(open('comp.txt').readlines())):\n  print line.strip()" | python
comp1
comp2
comp3
comp4
```

Comment: Try ``python -c "command"``. It is always better without unneeded pipes

Answer (score 0):

one thing can be done is knowing that set always starts with comp1 we can traverse from the end till the first "comp1" occurs. Once index of "comp1" is known from the end, we can print out the lines or last "set".

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{cnt = 0} {a[cnt1++] = $1; b[cnt2++] = $2;} 
END{for(i = NR; i >= 0; i--){if(a[0] == a[i]){cnt++;
if(cnt == 1){k= i;}}} for(j=k;j<NR;j++)print a[j],":",b[j];}' inputfile
```

a array collects comp entries, b array collects path entries, -F':' option used in awk command seperates both entries based on ':' delimiter.

**Or simpler way**,

```
awk '$1~/comp1/{cnt=NR}{array[count++]=$0}END{for(i=cnt-1;i<=NR;i++)print array[i]}'  
inputfile
```